# Virtual Keyboard qt how to put it in azerty

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I want to change the `VirtualKeyboard` to `[azerty]`.
I tried to put `VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale = "fr_FR"` but it doesn't work.
I also tried to put `CONFIG += lang-fr_FR` in the `.pro` file like it says in the Qt documentation but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what platform you are targeting, however Qt typically picks up on the runtime platform's locale setting, and applies this automatically wherever localisation is required, e.g. controls, dates, times, numbers etc. I would expect this to include the virtual keyboard.

However, if necessary you should be able to override the locale application-wide using `QLocale::setDefault`. See the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#setDefault).

If this doesn't work, please add some more information to your question so we can get a better idea of the problem.